# How to add values to an array with overriding

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add values into an array but I have noticed that array is only updating the latest value.

Here is my JSON response:

```
   {
      "NA":{
         "Date":"2023-06-19",
         "Time":"13:01:00",
         "Timezone":"PST"
      }
   },
   {
      "EU":{
         "Date":"2023-06-19",
         "Time":"13:01:00",
         "Timezone":"GMT"
      }
   },
   {
      "IN":{
         "Date":"2023-06-19",
         "Time":"13:01:00",
         "Timezone":"IST"
      }
   }
]
```

Whats happening is that when I insert the values into the array, it only adds the latest value to but ignores everything else so if there is only NA it will display NA but if there is NA, EU and IN it will only display IN. How would I go about having all the values show in the array?

```js
      var regionsData = JSON.parse(element[0]["regions"]);
      regionsData.forEach((value) => {
        dataObj.regions = [
          Object.keys(value) +
            " " +
            value[Object.keys(value)[0]].Date +
            " " +
            value[Object.keys(value)[0]].Time +
            " " +
            value[Object.keys(value)[0]].Timezone,
        ];
      });
```

element[0]["regions"] is the JSON response I listed, I am parsing it as it is being return as a string.

```js
    dataInfo.forEach((element) => {
      var dataObj = {
        audit_reference_id: element[0]["audit_reference_id"],
        subject: element[0]["subject"],
        leader_alias: element[0]["leader_alias"],
        exclude_user: element[0]["exclude_user"],
        regions: element[0]["regions"],
        exclusion_days: element[0]["exclusion_days"],
        escalation: element[0]["escalation"],
        job_family: element[0]["job_family"],
        creation_date: element[0]["creation_date"],
        created_by: element[0]["created_by"],
        updated_date: element[0]["updated_date"],
        updated_by: element[0]["updated_by"],
      };
```

Comment: In the `forEach` loop you are setting `dataObj.regions` equal to a new array. So `dataObj.regions` is only going to reflect the last value you set it to.

Maybe you want something like

`const newRegions = [];
regionsData.forEach(( value ) => newRegions.push( /* ... something ... */ )); dataObj.regions = newRegions;`

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, I over thought the problem! If you can answer it ill select it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `forEach` loop you are setting `dataObj.regions` equal to a new array. So `dataObj.regions` is only going to reflect the last value you set it to.

This should work instead:

```js
const newRegions = [];
regionsData.forEach((value) => {
  newRegions.push( /* ... something ... */ );
});
dataObj.regions = newRegions;
```

you can also simplify this to

```js
dataObj.regions = regionsData.map((value) => {
  return { /* ... some new object ... */ };
});
```